# JPA Join Custom query with OneToMany

Tags: spring, jpa

I would like to use @Query annotation to create left join query from a entity with a @OneToMany relationship.

Parent entity is :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Registration")
    public class Registration {

       @Column(nullable = false)
       @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
       private LocalDate effect;

       @OneToMany(targetEntity=Payment.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name="uuid")
       private List<Payment> payment;
   }
```

Child :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Payment")
    public class Payment {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
       @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
       @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
       private UUID uuid;
}
```

For DAO, I do like below :

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Registration r JOIN r.payment p WHERE r.effect = :effect")
Iterable<Payment> find(@Param("effect") LocalDate effect);
```

Obviously, its wrong because generated query is :

> select payment1_.uuid as uuid1_9_, payment1_.amount as amount2_9_ from registration registrati0_ inner join payment payment1_ on registrati0_.uuid=payment1_.uuid where registrati0_.effect=?

while the relation table has been generated:

[image]

For me, the correct query should be something like this :

> select p.* from registration r join registration_payment rp on rp.registration = r.uuid join payment p on p.uuid = rp.payment where r.effect = '2015-10-16'

What is the good query syntax please ? Actual query return en empty array.

Comment: What result do you expect? For me the sql match your query.

Comment: Actual query returns empty array, registrati0_.uuid=payment1_.uuid its not correct. Relation is inside the registration_payment table

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution.
You must describe relation table with @JoinTable :

```
@JoinTable(
        name="registration_payment",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="registration"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "payment")
)
private List<Payment> payment;
```

Modify @Query not needed :

> @Query("SELECT p FROM Registration r JOIN r.payment p WHERE r.effect = :effect")

Generated query is :

> select payment2_.uuid as uuid1_9_, payment2_.amount as amount2_9_
>   from registration registrati0_ 
>   inner join registration_payment payment1_ on registrati0_.uuid=payment1_.registration 
>   inner join payment payment2_ on payment1_.payment=payment2_.uuid 
>   where registrati0_.effect=?

Comment: Why it's created a JoinTable if you have OneToMany relationship, JoinTable is to ManyToMany.

Comment: @OneToMany create automatically join table registration_payment